# Session Times out after 20 mins using Identity Server Hybrid Flow with Cookie Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, identityserver4

I am fairly certain I am missing some configuration.

I am testing a new app using `Identity Server 4` with a ASP.NET core 1.0 website in a hybrid flow configured as below.

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
            SignInScheme = "Cookies",
            Authority = "https://account.testsite.com",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = true,
            ClientId = "superId",
            ClientSecret = "supersecretclient",

            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            Scope = { "api1", "offline_access", "profile", "openid" },

            GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
            SaveTokens = true,

            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
                RoleClaimType = "role"
            }
        });
```

Users keep getting logged out after 20 mins irrespective of their activity on the website.

Client config for IdSrv4 as follows:

`Absolute refresh time: 2592000
Access token lifetime: 3600
Authorization code lifetime: 300
Identity token lifetime: 300
Sliding refresh token lifetime: 1296000`

If the user hits refresh on the page, he is promptly logged back in automatically, however, the page has auto load features which fails.

Comment: what's the desired behavior you're expecting?

Comment: I am expecting the desired behavior to be more than an hour as per the access token lifetime as the default cookie time I believe is 29 days ...

Comment: first, in the question, you posted the client configuration, and the access token lifetime is 3600 seconds, so one hour. second, you can use the [`UseTokenLifetime`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/10ef26d63c98c3966e7315aee172a7c3fd992520/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs#L235) property on `OpenIdConnectOptions` to synchronise the lifetime of the session cookie with the lifetime of the token. Be aware, though, that it uses the **identity** token lifetime, not the access token one.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried with the official ASP Identity feature set, but I am implementing a third-party sign-on using Cookies.

There are a range of available options for the Cookie Authentication method. My example below is from my current application. The key ones are `SlidingExpiration` and `ExpireTimeSpan`

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() {
    CookieName = "Company.MyApp.Web." + env.EnvironmentName.ToLower(),
    AuthenticationScheme = "MyAppCookieAuth",
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login/"),
    AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/AccessDenied/"),
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2),
    SlidingExpiration = true
});
```

So when the Cookie is half expired, on the next page Request it will be refreshed. This may help persist their login for a longer period.

**More information on Cookie Authentication:**

Using Cookie Middleware without ASP.NET Core Identity -
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie

Introduction to Identity (contains sections pertaining to cookies) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity